# What is the error in this update query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, sql-update

```
UPDATE HotelSourceMap 
SET hsm.hotelid = co.hotelid 
FROM HotelSourceMap AS hsm 
JOIN hotels AS co 
ON (hsm.hotelname= co.[name] 
AND hsm.cityid = co.cityid)
```

It's giving me error: `The multi-part identifier "hsm.hotelid" could not be bound.`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming the field hotelid exists in the table try changing:

```
UPDATE HotelSourceMap SET hsm.hotelid ...
```

to

```
UPDATE HotelSourceMap hsm SET hsm.hotelid ...
```

or alternatively

```
UPDATE HotelSourceMap SET hotelid ...
```

Comment: wow..exactly what i want... its working gr8....


UPDATE    hsm
SET       hsm.hotelid  = co.hotelid 
FROM      HotelSourceMap AS hsm
    JOIN  hotels        AS co
    ON  hsm.hotelname= co.[name] AND hsm.cityid = co.cityid

Answer (score 1):

Try this :-

```
UPDATE 
    hsm
SET 
    hotelid = co.hotelid 
FROM 
    HotelSourceMap hsm,
    Hotels co
WHERE
  hsm.hotelname= co.[name] AND hsm.cityid = co.cityid
```

In your main statement, you say you want to update **HotelSourceMap**.

In your SET, you try to update a field belonging to a logically different entity, **hsm**.

Comment: Answered query.  Let me know if you need any more clarification.

Answer (score 0):

Correction, you need to use the alias as the UPDATE table:

```
UPDATE hsm
SET....
FROM HotelSourceMap AS hsm
....
```